# Updating object parameters appends ID to URL & throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-url

I have a users object in my rails app with a custom URL route. When I submit the update form, the user ID is being appended to the URL for some reason, and I'm getting a routing error.

routes:

```
 get     'myaccount' => 'users#show', as: 'user'  
 get     'myaccount/edit' => 'users#edit'
 patch   'myaccount/edit' => 'users#update'
 put     'myaccount/edit' => 'users#update'
```

view:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :form_object => @user %>

  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>


  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

controller action:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find_by(id: current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # successful update
    else
      # unsuccessful update
    end
  end
```

error:
 upon submitting, the URL is 'myaccount.7' and I get the error:
      Routing Error
        No route matches [PATCH] "/myaccount.7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have custom routes and Rails is confused where to send your form and which method to use. You should explicitly specify `url` and `method` options.

```
 <%= form_for(@user, url: 'myaccount/edit', action: :put)  do |f| %>
```

[Docs.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: Only addition is the url variable needed to be '/myaccount/edit' with the first char '/' otherwise the post URL was being rendered as '/myaccount/myaccount/edit'

Answer (score 0):

**try this** :

```
resources :myaccount, controller: 'users'
```

**output :**

```
  myaccount_index GET    /myaccount(.:format)                                                                users#index
                                         POST   /myaccount(.:format)                                                                users#create
                           new_myaccount GET    /myaccount/new(.:format)                                                            users#new
                          edit_myaccount GET    /myaccount/:id/edit(.:format)                                                       users#edit
                               myaccount GET    /myaccount/:id(.:format)                                                            users#show
                                         PATCH  /myaccount/:id(.:format)                                                            users#update
                                         PUT    /myaccount/:id(.:format)                                                            users#update
                                         DELETE /myaccount/:id(.:format)                                                            users#destroy
                                         GET    /myaccount(.:format)
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish my original goal of removing ID vars from the URL paths. I'd like the GET myaccount/:id to just be '/myaccount' and the edit to be '/myaccount/edit' not '/myaccount/:id/edit'

Comment: without id how can you identify, which is show , edit or delete